# How many bit strings containing exactly eight 0s and twelve 1s have either all the 0s consecutive, or all the 1s consecutive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many bit strings containing exactly eight 0s and twelve 1s have either all the 0s consecutive, or all the 1s consecutive?

i try use tree diagram to do it but it doesn't work that well, is there any other way to do this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, lets count the number of bit strings that have all the 0s consecutive. In this case, there are 13 different ways of placing the 0s relative to the 1s (you can have between 0 and 12 ones first, then all the 0s, and then the remaining 1s).

Next, the number of bit strings with all the 1s consecutive is 9, by the same logic as above. Finally, we have counted the strings where all the 0s and all the 1s are consecutive twice, which can happen in 2 ways (either the 0s first and then the 1s or the 1s first and then the 0s). All in all this gives $13+9-2=20$ bit strings.